# FFMPEG no metadata

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to dump all the important info using `ffmpeg.exe -i "1.mp4" -f ffmetadata metadata.txt` yet all I get is

```
;FFMETADATA1
major_brand=isom
minor_version=1
compatible_brands=isom
```

Official documentation gives no clues at all

Answer (score 0):

Try using ffprobe 
for example

c:\ffprobe fooc.mp4

```
bunch of other stuff is here

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'fooc.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: mp41
creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
Duration: 00:00:00.66, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1747 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 320x240 [SAR 45:44 DAR 15:11], 1738 kb/s, SAR 327:320 DAR 109:80, 12 fps, 12 tbr, 12 tbn, 12 tbc
Metadata:
creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
handler_name    : ♀VideoHandler
```

Comment: How to I make it export everything to a text file?

Comment: with an output stream redirection (ffprobe option filename > text.txt). I don't know if ffprobe  use stdout or stderr but just try 1> and 2>.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to write all of the metadata to a **copy** of the file - when I try writing to the file itself, it doesn't work!  Then it's just a case of deleting the original file(s) - both 'orig.mp4' and 'metadata.txt', ready for the next file operation.

```
ffmpeg -i "orig.mp4" -i metadata.txt -map_metadata 1 -c:a copy -id3v2_version 3 -write_id3v1 1 "copy.mp4"
```